# How to get the variables declared in the closure

Tags: groovy

How to get the variables declared in the closure, for example I can write

```
content{
a=1
b=2
}
when{}
then{}
```

in the block content I will receive data from a kafka topic or else I will make a call to a web service and as soon as I receive the data I will execute the block when and after the block then, so I declare the variables in the block content for example "data = sendRequest to web service" and then I use the data variable in the block when to make predicates.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?  What have you tried?  Why do you need to deal with such a closure?

Comment: I am trying to create a DLS with the following syntax .                                       
content{
a = 1;
b = 2;
}
when {
c = a + b
}
then {
assert c == 3
}
as a BDD framework (given, when, then)

Comment: Ok, but what is it used for? You are already getting answers to just create a map. What is a "content".  We need some context here.

Comment: ok, in the block content I will receive data from a kafka topic or else I will make a call to a web service and as soon as I receive the data I will execute the block when and after the block then, so I declare the variables in the block content for example "data = sendRequest to web service"
and then I use the data variable in the block when to make predicates

Comment: It surely would help to add those informations to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def map = [:]
map.with{
    a=1
    b=2
}

println map
```

result

```
[a:1, b:2]
```

Comment: Or `def map = [:].tap{ a = 1; b = 2 }` to be more direct